# Good way to display large text on the screen in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, xorg

I'd like to display a very large message, e.g. 1" high letters on the screen of a workstation.

I.e. something like "Today's stock price is $xx"

I could use gnome-terminal if I could set the font scale high enough, and the height to just one.

I tried zenity, but there doesn't seem to be a way to set the font size or get rid of the icon and 'ok' button.

Any recommendations?

---

ETA: the best I've done so far is

```
gnome-terminal --hide-menubar --zoom 4 --geometry 50x3 -e watch-stock.sh
```

Comment: You could create a `captcha` and use that as background image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A nice & funny way to do it

```
$ xx='12'
$ figlet "Today's stock price is $xx"
 _____         _             _           _             _    
|_   _|__   __| | __ _ _   _( )___   ___| |_ ___   ___| | __
  | |/ _ \ / _` |/ _` | | | |// __| / __| __/ _ \ / __| |/ /
  | | (_) | (_| | (_| | |_| | \__ \ \__ \ || (_) | (__|   < 
  |_|\___/ \__,_|\__,_|\__, | |___/ |___/\__\___/ \___|_|\_\
                       |___/                                
            _            _       _ ____  
 _ __  _ __(_) ___ ___  (_)___  / |___ \ 
| '_ \| '__| |/ __/ _ \ | / __| | | __) |
| |_) | |  | | (_|  __/ | \__ \ | |/ __/ 
| .__/|_|  |_|\___\___| |_|___/ |_|_____|
```

Just run

```
sudo apt-get install figlet
```

before ;)

### A programmable text box using QT & python

[image: qt+python]

The code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# simple text box with configurable font size
# require the price as script argument
myFontSize = 60

from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore
import sys

def main():

    app     = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    palette = QtGui.QPalette()
    label   = QtGui.QLabel("Today's stock price is $" + sys.argv[1])

    palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Foreground,QtCore.Qt.green)
    label.setPalette(palette)

    label.resize(800, 150)
    font = label.font()
    font.setPixelSize(myFontSize)
    label.setFont(font)

    label.setWindowTitle('PyQt QLabel Text Color')
    label.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I run the script like this in a terminal :

```
python script.py 12
```

You need to install python's qt binding :

```
sudo apt-get install python-qt4
```

Comment: +1 for writing a script. Of course, now I have to install Qt4 to use it...

Comment: Yes, I think you need python-qt4, tell me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

What about using [`sm` (`screen-message`)](http://packages.debian.org/sid/sm) It works from your terminal, although you can assign a key combination for quick access it's also [available on your browser](http://sm.nomeata.de/#t=:-%29) (tested in iceweasel/firefox) The link to the author page is here --> `http://www.joachim-breitner.de/projects`

Good luck!

Comment: That's a nice little app. Unfortunately, it completely fills the screen, while I just wanted a window with large text. I'm sure I'll find other uses for this app, though.

Comment: What about background transparency?